# HTTP Range: bytes with WebClient C#

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I am trying to resume file download.

I use the below code to successfully download the file I need.

```
    downlaodfile = new WebClient();
  // downlaodfile.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=0-600000");
downlaodfile.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(video.DownloadUrl), @"C:\Videofile.pm4");
```

The problem start when I uncomment the bellow line I get 0 bytes downloaded

```
 downlaodfile.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=0-600000");
```

What is the right way to resume with WebClient class?

Comment: Note that server must also support resuming downloads

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you cannot set the Range header the way you are trying to set it. To verify that simply subscribe to the `DownloadFileCompleted` event and dump the error:

```
downlaodfile.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
};
```

You will get this printed:

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> System.ArgumentException: The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name
   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.ThrowOnRestrictedHeader(String headerName)
   at System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(String name, String value)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Headers(WebHeaderCollection value)
   at System.Net.WebClient.CopyHeadersTo(WebRequest request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebRequest(Uri address)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFileAsync(Uri address, String fileName, Object userToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

OK, so you might need a custom WebClient:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    private readonly long from;
    private readonly long to;

    public WebClientEx(long from, long to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AddRange(this.from, this.to);
        return request;
    }
}
```

that you could use like this:

```
downlaodfile = new WebClientEx(0, 600000);
downlaodfile.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(video.DownloadUrl), @"C:\Videofile.pm4");
```

or simply use the `HttpWebRequest` class instead of a `WebClient`:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(video.DownloadUrl);
request.AddRange(0, 600000);
using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var output = File.Create(@"C:\Videofile.pm4"))
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(output);
}
```

or if you prefer with an `HttpClient`:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(0, 600000);
using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(video.DownloadUrl))
using (var output = File.Create(@"C:\Videofile.pm4"))
{
    await stream.CopyToAsync(output);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I decide to dump the WebClient and I managed to do the Range Byte with WebRequest. successfully